# C# serializing Class to XML where one of class properties is DateTime. How to make this property in ISO format?

Tags: datetime, xml-serialization

I'm serializing class which contains DateTime property.

```
public DateTime? Delivered { get; set; }
```

After serializing Delivered node contains DateTime formatted like this:

```
2008-11-20T00:00:00
```

How can I change this property to make it look like this:

```
2008-11-20 00:00:00
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The hack I use for odd formatting during XmlSerialization is to have a special property that is only used during XmlSerialization

```
//normal DateTime accessor
[XmlIgnore]
public DateTime Delivered { get; set; }

//special XmlSerialization accessor
[XmlAttribute("DateTime")]
public string XmlDateTime
{
    get { return this.Delivered.ToString("o"); }
    set { this.Delivered = new DateTime.Parse(value); }
}
```

Comment: I believe you mean "this.Delivered" instead of "this.DateTime"?

Comment: my DateTime property is nullable (DateTime?) does this change a lot?

Comment: Perhaps this should be moved to "hackoverflow"?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [XmlAttributeOverrides class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides(VS.71).aspx).